# Why is time difference on calculating this so big?

Tags: python

I need to round lots of UNIX timestamps down to their respective minutes (expressed as timestamp again).

Out of pure curiosity I timed two methods:

```
%timeit (127/60)*60
10000000 loops, best of 3: 76.2 ns per loop

%timeit 127 - 127%60
10000000 loops, best of 3: 34.1 ns per loop
```

I ran this several times and second method is consistently around twice as fast as first one. Why is the difference so big?

Comment: Division is much more expensive than multiplication, subtraction and modulo operation.

Comment: Which version of Python?  I'm wondering whether `/` here is integer division or floating division.

Comment: @TimPeters if both arguments are integers then / is an integer division.

Comment: @TimPeters: 2.7, x64, Linux

Comment: @DanKruchinin, not true:  in Python3, `/` is floating division even if both operands are integers.  `//` is integer division in Python 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> import dis
>>> method1 = lambda: (127 / 60) * 60
>>> method2 = lambda: 127 - 127 % 60
>>> dis.dis(method1)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (127)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (60)
              6 BINARY_DIVIDE       
              7 LOAD_CONST               2 (60)
             10 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             11 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(method2)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (127)
              3 LOAD_CONST               3 (7)
              6 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

In the second case, the modulo operation is simply optimized away.

Comment: haha, nice :) i think a smart compiler would optimize the whole expression away, no matter how it is written...

Comment: @Vasiliy: slap, forehead

Comment: In real life, I think the value 127 would be passed in as a variable rather than a constant, in which case that optimisation in m2 goes away.

Answer (score 3):

Division is heavy operation relative to other operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `%`) according to following timeit results:

```
In [9]: timeit 127 + 12
100000000 loops, best of 3: 14.8 ns per loop

In [10]: timeit 127 - 12
100000000 loops, best of 3: 14.8 ns per loop

In [11]: timeit 127 * 12
100000000 loops, best of 3: 14.9 ns per loop

In [12]: timeit 127 / 12
10000000 loops, best of 3: 40 ns per loop

In [13]: timeit 127 % 12
100000000 loops, best of 3: 14.7 ns per loop
```

**UPDATE**

I was wrong. Using varaible, shows different results as Tim Peters commented.

```
In [1]: a, b = 127, 12

In [2]: timeit a + b
10000000 loops, best of 3: 37.6 ns per loop

In [3]: timeit a - b
10000000 loops, best of 3: 37.9 ns per loop

In [4]: timeit a * b
10000000 loops, best of 3: 52.7 ns per loop

In [5]: timeit a / b
10000000 loops, best of 3: 54 ns per loop

In [6]: timeit a % b
10000000 loops, best of 3: 56.5 ns per loop
```

Comment: Better to use variables, since the compiler *may* optimize away operations on literals.

Comment: @TimPeters, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer to include variable version.

Comment: @falsetru: there's still a difference though, have a=127, p=60 and run `%timeit a - a%p` vs `%timeit (a/p)*p`. So Tim were right and you were haf-right. :-)

Comment: @JohnDoe, I updated the answer to include varaible version. I'm Sorry.

Comment: For more fun, try it under Python 3 ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters, I tried `a+b`, `a-b`, `a*b`, `a/b`, `a%b` in Python 3.3.1 (32bit, Linux, same machine). It produced 72.5ns, 72.2ns, 90.7ns, 85ns, 101ns.

Comment: Sounds about right - it's a consequence of `int` and `long` becoming the same type (what Py2 called `long` and Py3 calls `int`) in Py3. And one consequence of *that* is that the Py3 eval loop no longer special-cases the snot out of (what used to be) `int`s.  Win some, lose some ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is really a question of your specific computer hardware, perhaps having to do with [pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28computing%29) and [ALU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) details, as well as how those loops are actually being executed natively, so I can't answer definitively. But my guess would be that in this particular chunk of code, multiply, divide, and modulus all take roughly the same amount of time, and that time is greater than add or subtract. So you have two slower operations in example 1, but only one in example 2.

Edit: as falsetru shows in his answer, it could be a question of division versus the other operations. But again, it's not possible to say definitely without more details.